# Searching for backslash character in vim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

How to search word start `\word` in vim. I can do it using the find menu. Is there any other short cut for this?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you looking for words that start with 'word' or with '\word' or just the pattern '\word' whether it is at the beginning of a word or not?

Comment: The question title made specific reference to backslash, so it wouldn't just be "word".

Comment: I fixed most typos but one: Should that be "I can" or "I can't"?

Comment: @Aaron: I read it as "can", as in the OP currently does it that way but wants a better one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `/\\word` in command mode.

This works because, to escape a special character, we precede it with a backslash (`\`). Since `\` is a special character (and one you want to actually search for), we escape it with backslash.

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-7612/editorvi-62/index.html#:%7E:text=To%20escape%20a%20special%20character,commands%20to%20the%20search%20function)

Answer (score 4):

You can search for most anything in your document using regular expressions.  From normal mode, type '/' and then start typing your regular expression, and then press enter.  '\<' would match the beginning of a word, so

```
/\<foo
```

would match the string 'foo' but only where it is at the beginning of a word (preceded by whitespace in most cases).

You can search for the backslash character by escaping it with a backslash, so:

```
/\<\\foo
```

Would find the pattern '\foo' at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Combine your answer and mine, and you get: /\<\\word :-)

Comment: `\<\\` isn't particularly meaningful, though: `\` isn't a word character.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly relevant (`/\\word` is the the correct solution, and nothing here changes that), but for your information:

[`:h magic`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic)

If you are for a pattern with many characters with special meaning to regexes, you may find "nomagic" and "very nomagic" mode useful.

```
/\V^.$
```

will search for the literal string `^.$`, instead of "lines of exactly one character" (`\v` "very magic" and the default `\m` "magic" modes) or "lines of exactly one period" (`\M` "nomagic" mode).

Answer (score 3):

The reason searching for something including "\" is different is because "\" is a special character and needs to be escaped (prepended with a backslash)

Similarly, to search for "$100", which includes the special character "$":

```
Press /
Type \$100
Press return
```

To search for "abc", which doesn't include a special character:

```
Press /
Type abc
Press return
```